# How to select (and do calculations with) a row and the row below it

Tags: r, if-statement

My dataframe looks like this:

```
      var1      var2    var3
1     0         5       "other"
2     25        3       "sample"
3     4         5       "other"
4     60        5       "other"
5     4         5       "other"
6     60        5       "other"
7     25        3       "sample"
8     4         8       "other"
9     60        7       "other"
10    4         3       "other"  
11    25        27      "sample"  
12    4         9       "other"   
13    30        4       "other"
```

I would like to add a column that for all rows that equal var3=="sample" gives the calculation of the value in var2 column minus the value in var 2 column of the row beneath the "sample" row. That would look like this:

```
      var1      var2    var3      var4
1     0         5       "other"   NA
2     25        25      "sample"  20
3     4         5       "other"   NA
4     60        5       "other"   NA
5     4         5       "other"   NA
6     60        5       "other"   NA
7     25        13      "sample"  8
8     4         5       "other"   NA
9     60        5       "other"   NA
10    4         3       "other"   NA
11    25        27      "sample"  18
12    4         9       "other"   NA
13    30        4       "other"   NA
```

I have tried

```
if(df$var3=="sample") {df$var4<-(df$var2-df$var2[+1,])}
```

But that obviously doesn't work. How to do a calculation with a column from a specific row and the exact row beneath it?

Comment: Is it not possible to filter the table on 'sample' and `diff(df$var2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subtract by the `lead` i.e. next element of 'var2' when the 'var3' is 'sample'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(var4 = ifelse(var3 == "sample", var2 -lead(var2), NA))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = c(0L, 25L, 4L, 60L, 4L, 60L, 25L, 4L, 60L, 
4L, 25L, 4L, 30L), var2 = c(5L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 27L, 9L, 4L), var3 = c("other", "sample", "other", "other", 
"other", "other", "sample", "other", "other", "other", "sample", 
"other", "other")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You're faster than me this morning! This is identical to the answer I would have provided.

Comment: Thankyou very much! Would it also be possible for the exact row above the var3=="sample" row :)?

Comment: @R_beginner_22  Sure add `%>% filter(var3 == "sample")` to the above

Comment: @akrun @Steven  I tried 
    `library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(var4 = ifelse(var3 == "sample", var2 -lead(var2), NA))`
but unfortunately I get an error saying
`Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` 
any idea what I did wrong?:(

Comment: @R_beginner_22  I updated with the data I used.  Please check the str of your dataset.

Comment: @akrun Thankyou very much for your help! I changed my str to integer and character, now it works!